# inserting data into a mysql table dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

Forgive me for lack of a proper question title but my question is as below

I have a table with data that look like this:

```
    mysql> select * from tablex;

+-------+---------+-----+
| id  | post_id   | pid |
+-------+---------+-----+
| 14549 |    7195 |  27 |
| 14551 |    7195 |  34 |
| 14556 |    7195 |   1 |
| 14564 |    7196 |  51 |
| 14566 |    7196 |  11 |
| 14571 |    7196 |  37 |
| 14576 |    7197 |  36 |
| 14578 |    7198 |  11 |
| 14586 |    7199 |  15 |
| 14612 |    7201 |  42 |
+-------+---------+-----+
```

When i do a count for duplicates, i get a data structure like this:

```
mysql> select count(*), post_id from tablex group by post_id;
+----------+---------+
| count(*) | post_id |
+----------+---------+
|        3 |    7195 |
|        3 |    7196 |
|        1 |    7197 |
|        1 |    7198 |
|        1 |    7199 |
|        1 |    7201 |
+----------+---------+
```

I am seeking ideas of how best to manipulate the data above using php/mysql to update tabley to look like this

```
mysql> select * from tabley order by meta_id desc;
+---------+---------+------------------+---------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key         | meta_value    |
+---------+---------+------------------+---------------+
|    7575 |     7195| multiple         |       3       |
|    7574 |     7195| multiple_0       |      27       |
|    7573 |     7195| multiple_1       |      34       |
|    7572 |     7195| multiple_2       |      1        |
|         |         |                  |               |
+---------+---------+------------------+---------------+
```

You will notice that post_id 7195 occurs 3 times,so the first step is to set meta_key multiple to 3.

The next step is to run a loop and create key 0-2 and create meta keys mutiple_0 - multiple_2 and insert values 27,34,1 that correspond to post_id 7195 as can be seen from  tablex ...Which is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: what is meta_id and meta_value in tabley?

Comment: @sree Meta_id is the primary key (auto_increment), meta_value is the pid from tablex

Comment: Each post_id you need to insert to tabley like this?

Comment: Yes. if count(post_id) is one, then the pid should be just one value and if they are three then they should be three values

Comment: @sree your solution below does not enter the correct data for "meta_value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code . Don't forget to change the servername,username,password and database

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password','database');
  $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select count(*) as count,post_id from tablex group by post_id");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){   
        $count[]=$row["count"];
        $postid[]=$row["post_id"];
        }
        foreach (array_combine($postid,$count) as $pid=>$cnt){

            for($i=0;$i<=$cnt;$i++){
                $pstid = $pid;
                if($i==0){
                $multiple = "multiple";
                $meta= $cnt;
                }
                else{
                    $x=$i-1;
                    $multiple = "multiple_".$x;
                    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select pid from tablex where post_id='$pid'");
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
                    $id[]=$row["pid"];
                    }
                    $meta = $id[$i-1];
                }
$query2=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO tabley(post_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES('$pid','$multiple','$meta')");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use only `mysql` for this operation

```
INSERT INTO tabley (
    post_id,
    meta_key,
    meta_value
) SELECT 
    t1.post_id,
    'multiple' AS multiple,
    COUNT(*)
FROM tablex AS t1 GROUP BY t1.post_id
UNION
SELECT
    t2.post_id,
    REPLACE(
        CONCAT(
            'multiple_',
            @curRow:=CASE
                WHEN @postId = t2.post_id THEN @curRow + 1
                ELSE 0
            END,
            @postId:=t2.post_id
        ),
        t2.post_id,
        ''
    ) AS multiple,
    t2.pid
FROM tablex AS t2
ORDER BY post_id, multiple;
```

First part is `INSERT ... SELECT` mysql syntax.
And `UNION` second select. You can test `SELECT`'s without `INSERT`

Second part is get row number for rows with similar `post_id`.