# Sql query returning different results in php from those in mysql shell

Tags: php, mysql

This question is originates from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308273/inserting-data-into-a-mysql-table-dynamically).

When i run this script  on mysql shell (see below)

```html
mysql> SELECT 
    ->     t1.post_id,
    ->     'multiple' AS multiple,
    ->     COUNT(*) as count
    -> FROM people_publication AS t1 GROUP BY t1.post_id
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT
    ->     t2.post_id,
    ->     REPLACE(
    ->         CONCAT(
    ->             'multiple_',
    ->             @curRow:=CASE
    ->                 WHEN @postId = t2.post_id THEN @curRow + 1
    ->                 ELSE 0
    ->             END,
    ->             @postId:=t2.post_id
    ->         ),
    ->         t2.post_id,
    ->         ''
    ->     ) AS multiple,
    ->     t2.pid
    -> FROM people_publication AS t2
    -> ORDER BY post_id, multiple;
+---------+------------+-------+
| post_id | multiple   | count |
+---------+------------+-------+
|    7209 | multiple   |     3 |
|    7209 | multiple_0 |    27 |
|    7209 | multiple_1 |    34 |
|    7209 | multiple_2 |     1 |
|    7210 | multiple   |     3 |
|    7210 | multiple_0 |    51 |
|    7210 | multiple_1 |    11 |
|    7210 | multiple_2 |    37 |
|    7211 | multiple   |     1 |
|    7211 | multiple_0 |    36 |
|    7212 | multiple   |     1 |
|    7212 | multiple_0 |    11 |
|    7213 | multiple   |     1 |
|    7213 | multiple_0 |    15 |
|    7215 | multiple   |     1 |
|    7215 | multiple_0 |    42 |
+---------+------------+-------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

i get different results compared when i run the same script with php

```html
$query = "SELECT 
    t1.post_id,
    'multiple' AS multiple,
    COUNT(*) as count
FROM people_publication AS t1 GROUP BY t1.post_id
UNION
SELECT
    t2.post_id,
    REPLACE(
        CONCAT(
            'multiple_',
            @curRow:=CASE
                WHEN @postId = t2.post_id THEN @curRow + 1
                ELSE 0
            END,
            @postId:=t2.post_id
        ),
        t2.post_id,
        ''
    ) AS multiple,
    t2.pid
FROM people_publication AS t2
ORDER BY post_id, multiple";

$sql=$con->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 while($row=$sql->fetch()){
  echo "<pre>";print_r($row);
        }
```

which returns a table that looks like this (see below)

```html
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key   | meta_value |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|     816 |    7209 | multiple   | 3          |
|     817 |    7209 | multiple_0 | 34         |
|     818 |    7209 | multiple_0 | 1          |
|     819 |    7209 | multiple_0 | 27         |
|     820 |    7210 | multiple   | 3          |
|     821 |    7210 | multiple_0 | 37         |
|     822 |    7210 | multiple_0 | 51         |
|     823 |    7210 | multiple_0 | 11         |
|     824 |    7211 | multiple   | 1          |
|     825 |    7211 | multiple_0 | 36         |
|     826 |    7212 | multiple   | 1          |
|     827 |    7212 | multiple_0 | 11         |
|     828 |    7213 | multiple   | 1          |
|     829 |    7213 | multiple_0 | 15         |
|     830 |    7215 | multiple   | 1          |
|     831 |    7215 | multiple_0 | 42         |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
```

What causes this to happen?

The connection file looks like this

```html
<?php
//session_start();
function dbConnect() {
  $host = 'localhost';
  $dbname = 'mydb';
  $user = 'root';
  $pass = '';
    try {
    $con= new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
return $con;
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } 

catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Cannot connect to database';
      exit();
    }
  
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the mysql connection class in your php code

one more thing to check that on localhost mysql connects using sockets while on server it uses port. It could cause an issue if they are to different instance

Comment: the mysql connection class is well defined with the coreect credentials, and the server and the localhost are both fine

Comment: Could you please check mysql link id and link connection parameter in php code

Comment: Hi @Satyapal. I have ammended the question to include the connection code

Comment: I might not have understood you. What exactly do you mean when you say i check mysql link id and connection parameter?

Comment: Use print_r($con); in this file thaen fire a query and see what the output is

Comment: it returns PDO Object()